# VSCode: How to open terminal in editor area to the bottom instead of the side?

Tags: visual-studio-code

In VSCode, I would like to get the following layout with the Code editor on top and the Terminals on the bottom as tabs.

[image: Vscode layout]

When I press Cmd+Shift+T, I would like to get a new terminal tab opening under (and not aside) the active editor. And then I'd like to press Cmd+T to open a new terminal as a tab.

I did the following bindings.

```json
[
    // Terminal
    {
        "key": "cmd+t",
        "command": "-workbench.action.showAllSymbols"
    },
    {
        "key": "shift+cmd+t",
        "command": "-workbench.action.reopenClosedEditor"
    },
    {
        "key": "shift+cmd+t",
        "command": "workbench.action.createTerminalEditorSide"
    },
    {
        "key": "cmd+t",
        "command": "workbench.action.createTerminalEditor"
    },

]
```

It almost works: Shift+T opens a new Terminal tab editor, and Shift+Cmd+T opens a new terminal

But:

- Shift+Cmd+T opens a terminal tab at the **right instead of bottom** of the active editor
- Shift+T systematically opens a tab **in the upper tabs** list, even if the active editor is a terminal

*Please note I know about the Terminals tabs in Panels, but the nesting is too deep to me and I prefer dealing with tabs.*

Answer (score 0):

You can [run multiple commands with a single keybinding](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/keybindings#_running-multiple-commands) using the `runCommands` command. The following configuration opens a new terminal in the editor (which always happens in the first editor group as you already noticed) and then moves it into an editor group below via a single <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>. If there is no editor group below, VSCode implicitly creates a new one, otherwise it reuses the existing one, hence you don't need a separate keybinding to create follow-up terminals.

```json
[
    // Terminal
    {
        "key": "shift+cmd+t",
        "command": "-workbench.action.reopenClosedEditor"
    },
    {
        "key": "shift+cmd+t",
        "command": "runCommands",
        "args": {
            "commands": [
                "workbench.action.createTerminalEditor",
                "workbench.action.moveEditorToBelowGroup",
            ]
        },
    },
]
```